# Unknown character in HTML scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping

Here is the code I used to scrape the data

```php
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://websitename.com/videoname.html');
preg_match_all( '|<source.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i',$html, $matches ); 
echo $matches[ 1 ][ 0 ];
?>
```

It takes data from the following HTML line

```html
<video id="f-player"><source src="https://websitename.com/video/143.mp4?secl=1bYfG7HEZeTr2KOAMwp6QA&sect=1581943226"></video>            
</div>
```

The `"secl=1bYfG7HEZeTr2KOAMwp6QA&sect=1581943226"` frequently changes, that is why I want to use this script.

It is able to collect data but the out put is like this

> [https://websitename.com/video/143.mp4?secl=1bYfG7HEZeTr2KOAMwp6QA§=1581943226](https://websitename.com/video/143.mp4?secl=1bYfG7HEZeTr2KOAMwp6QA%C2%A7=1581943226)

The `&sect` was replaced by `§`!
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
<?php

/**
* get_links()
*
* @param string $url
* @return array
*/
function get_links($url) {

    // Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    // Load the url's contents into the DOM
    $xml->loadHTMLFile($url);

    // Empty array to hold all links to return
    $links = array();

    //Loop through each <source> tag in the dom and add it to the link array
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('source') as $link) {
        $links[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('src'));
    }

    //Return the links
    return $links;
}
?>
```

try to use above function like

```
$links = get_links('https://websitename.com/videoname.html');
```

Comment: cant understand how to apply, too difficult for me!!

Comment: just use code-1 and add code-2 in the end of code-1 than replace `https://websitename.com/videoname.html` with your url and in the end `print_r($links);` you will get what you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the output is
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => https://websitename/video/143.mp4?secl=oReO3eP0dDDIYsdV5xTIsg§=1581945515 ) )

§is still there

Comment: `$links[] = array('url' => str_replace("§","&sect", $link->getAttribute('src'));` try to replace this

Comment: it gives error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in  on line 28

Comment: try to copy once again

Comment: got it add one more closing bracket in end `$links[] = array('url' => str_replace("§","&sect", $link->getAttribute('src')));`

Comment: new error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in /home/customer/www/nextinweb.com/public_html/test1/index.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/nextinweb.com/public_html/test1/index.php on line 28

Comment: what is the actual url ?